# Decrypt password with openssl

Tags: openssl

I have an old shell script, created by a person that is not in the company anymore, to encrypt and decrypt our access password.
The old script is basically this:

```
PFILE=/home/user/keys/pwfile
if [ ! -f $PFILE ] || [[ "$NEW_FILE" == "true" ]]; then
    rm -rf $PFILE
    echo "PASSWORD=notset" >> $PFILE
fi
if [ -n "$PASSWORD" ]; then
    echo "changing PASSWORD"
    P=`echo ${PASSWORD} | openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -a -salt -pass pass:${SECRET}`
    sed -i "/PASSWORD=/ s|=.*|=${P}|" ${PFILE}
fi
```

And to decrypt the script basically did this:

```
PASSWORD=$(sed -n 's|^PASSWORD=||p' $PFILE)
password=`echo $PASSWORD | openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -a -d -salt -pass pass:${SECRET}`
```

But now when I run this, I get the error:

```
*** WARNING : deprecated key derivation used.
Using -iter or -pbkdf2 would be better.
```

I created a test script to try this new version and it looks like this:

```
P=`echo 'rawpassword' | openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -md sha512 -pbkdf2 -iter 1000 -salt -pass pass:'secret'`    
echo "P = " $P    
U= `echo P | openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -md sha512 -pbkdf2 -iter 1000 -d -salt -pass pass:'secret'`    
echo "U = " $U
```

Seems like it's working to encrypt, but I'm doing something wrong during the decryption, as it's printing an empty string and giving me the error:

```
error reading input file
```

What am I doing wrong during the decryption?

Comment: An warning is not an error. would redirecting openssl to stderr on the old script work? as in `openssl ....` 2> /dev/null

Comment: remove the space after equal sign `U= `

Comment: @user4556274, removing the space still gives the same error.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro, this is what openssl gives me when I decrypt the passwords:
▒▒z~
    u1׬▒▒▒▒[▒
i ▒(▒xގ▒Zy▒K▒2▒

Comment: You want `U=\`echo $P ...` instead of `U= \`echo P ...`